# Issue on Group Sequence Validator in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm new on Symfony2 world. I was trying to learn the basics of Validation in Symfony2 when I ran into a problem with it. According to the [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence), to manage properly a sequence of validation groups you have to add this annotation's line on your `Entity` class:

```
/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"User", "Strict"})
 */
```

And put some annotation wherever you want to handle the proper rule. In my case as well as one of the guide is the `password` field that should be valid only if firstly it has compiled (and respects my rules such as minimum length) and then if is different from `username` value. The problem is it doesnt' work for me!

I mean, I have the same `User` class and I used the same form of their example:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user, array('validation_groups' => array('signup','strict')))
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('signup', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

Here's my `User` class:

```
<?php

namespace XXX\SiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"User", "signup", "strict"}) 
 */
class User
{
    //..

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"signup"})
     * @Assert\Length(min=3,groups={"signup"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"signup"})
     * @Assert\Length(min=7,groups={"signup"})     
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"signup"})     
     * @Assert\Email(checkMX=true, groups={"signup"})     
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @Assert\True(groups={"strict"})
     */
    public function isPasswordLegal()
    {
        return $this->name != $this->password;
    }

    //..some getter\setter methods
}
```

When I submit the form without putting values in the fields it shows me every error (and that's right) but also one that `isPasswordLegal()` launches, even BEFORE the others!

What am I missing? Thank you all!

Comment: What happens if you remove the groups from the form?

Comment: If you mean to remove the `validation_groups` array from the `createFormBuilder` function it just won't check "signup" group properties.

Comment: I've just checked - it works here. Don't you by any chance have a YML mapping at the same time with notations?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the error is displayed before the others is, that you use it as a method validator and Symfony assigns the error message to the form instance and not the form field.

**Edit:**

All forms provide the [`error_mapping` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-mapping) which lets you define where the error messages should be shown.

In your case it would look like this:

```
$options = array(
    'validation_groups' => array('signup','strict'),
    'error_mapping' => array(
        'isPasswordLegal' => 'password',
    ),
);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user, $options)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'text')
    ->add('password', 'password')
    ->add('signup', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```